# Hide an image within header on one page, the online form only

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, forms

I have a giant image/button in my header on every page that leads my users to a form they fill out, I want to remove that image/button on the form page itself, hoping to use css. I'm using wordpress, but this form is not a wordpress page, its located in a different directory and its called index.php. How do I go about hiding the image?

Within index.php, the first few lines there is a call to get_header() which loads the header so i thought to put this bit of code right after it:

```
<?php if ( is_page('mysite.org/the-index-page/') ) { ?>
<style type = "text/css">.order-btn { display: none; }</style>
<?php } ?>
```

however nothing happens. Am I doing this right or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: have you made sure ".order-btn" is correctly tagged on the image? For example, if in IE, the easy way to check is press F12 and use the Developer tools DOM explorer to locate the image and click on it. You can then easily examine and understand what is tagged with the image and the update your code as necessary

Comment: .order-btn is a div class that the image and text within it is located. i just want to hide the entire div.

Comment: So how about adding an id to the div (if not already there), and then use javascript to search for the id and set style as display:none

Comment: Im just trying to avoid javascript, I wanted to learn it in php. I'm not very good at using javascript haha.

Comment: the css should have worked (maybe you already managed to do with the answer below)... anyway, you can try display: none !important; to see if it makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is probably to remove the button from that specific page. It sounds as if the button markup is inside your header.php file. You could try this:

```
<?php if ( !is_page( 'the-index-page' ) ) : ?>
    // Button markup here
<?php endif; ?>
```

And if it's not working, this should:

```
$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

<?php if ( !( $url == 'mysite.org/the-index-page/' ) ) : ?>
    // Button markup here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Like its not a wp page, if u click pages in wp admin area, its not listed there.

Comment: What is it then? If you're using a plugin it might help if you to tell which one and how it's configured.

Comment: Its a php form I made, I just didn't make it using wordpress is all I meant by that.

Comment: Check my updated answser. The second solution is a bit uglier, so if you could figure out what "the-index-page" is and find the appropriate function to check for it in WP, that's probably better.

Comment: if the div I want to be hidden is in my header.php file, should I put this code in header as well? I don't know exactly the best place to put this

Comment: Yes, put the html you want to hide where I've put the comment about button markup